# Use fminsearch to find local minimizer and the minima at that value

Tags: matlab, function, fminsearch

I am having trouble using `fminsearch`: getting the error that there were not enough input arguments for my function.

```
f = @(x1,x2,x3) x1.^2 + 3.*x2.^2 + 4.*x3.^2 - 2.*x1.*x2 + 5.*x1 + 3.*x2 + 2.*x3;
[x, val] = fminsearch(f,0)
```

Is there something wrong with my function? I keep getting errors anytime I want to use it as an input function with any other command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am having trouble using `fminsearch` [...]

Stop right there and think some more about the function you're trying to minimize.

Numerical optimization (which is what `fminsearch` does) is unnecessary, here. Your function is a quadratic function of vector `x`; in other words, its value at `x` can be expressed as

```
x^T A x + b^T x
```

where matrix `A` and vector `b` are defined as follows (using MATLAB notation):

```
A = [ 1 -1 0;
     -1  3 0;
      0  0 4]
```

and

```
b = [5 3 2].'
```

Because `A` is positive definite, your function has one and only one minimum, which can be computed in MATLAB with

```
x_sol = -0.5 * A \ b;
```

---

Now, if you're curious about the cause of the error you ran into, have a look at [fuesika's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30631018/2541573); but do without `fminsearch` whenever you can.

Comment: Nice job in noticing that the function is in quadratic form. +1.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly what Matlab is telling you: your function expects three arguments. You are passing only one.

Instead of

```
[x, val] = fminsearch(f,0)
```

you should call it like

```
[x, val] = fminsearch(f,[0,0,0])
```

since you define the function `f` to accept a three dimensional vector as input only.

You can read more about the specification of `fminsearch` in the online documentation at http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html:

> x = fminsearch(fun,x0) starts at the point x0 and returns a value x
>   that is a local minimizer of the function described in fun. **x0 can be
>   a scalar, vector, or matrix.** fun is a function_handle.